# How to add images to Firebase Storage from google drive?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

For my iOS app, I want users to be able to access a set of images (but not add any images themselves) that I provide. However, I am going to add more images to this set after the app is already published, so I was thinking the best way to configure this is by adding those images to Firebase storage (the app already is using FirebaseAuthentication and Firestore). The images will already be on Google Drive. Do I need to add them to Firebase Storage programmatically or is there an easier way? Alternatively, is there a better way to be adding images to the app after the app is already published? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Franks answer is correct but I was thinking of a solution more from a logistics and implementation perspective. We don't know your entire use case so a specific answer isn't possible but let me present one scenario.

1. You have an 'admin' app. With this app, you can take pictures and then upload them to Firebase Storage where the existing images are stored. The URL's to those images are stored in Firestore. The images can be added, edited or removed from your admin app, and when that happens, the images the users have access to is also modified
2. The users have a client app. This app allows them to view the images you have uploaded to Storage based on the URL's stored in Firestore.

Discussion:

The client apps observe a collection called 'Available Images' that looks like this

```
Available_Images
   image_0
      image_url: "points to some storage url"
      image_name: "the name of the image"
   image_1
      image_url: "points to another storage url"
      image_name: "this image name"
```

As your admin app adds, edits or removes images from the Available_Images node, the client apps are automatically notified of this change (because they are observing the Available_Images collection) and so the images they have access to are automatically updated.

You could modify the data in the Firebase console - upload an image to storage, get the URL and then add it to the Available_Images but that's a very manual process.

Having an 'admin' app could make that process very automated; take a picture, click or tap the 'upload image' button and all of the clients can access that new image.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to serve the images from Firestore Storage, you will have to upload the images to Storage yourself. Luckily both Drive and Storage have APIs, so it should be a fairly simple matter to copy them over.

If **you** are the only one changing the images, I'd also consider storing them in Firebase Hosting. This makes them available to your app through Firebase Hosting's CDN, meaning that your users will get them faster - at a slightly increased [cost](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) to you. You'll need to store the list of files somewhere in a known location in this case though, as there is no public API to list the files in Firebase Hosting, like there is for Storage.